# add a piece of text to a variable if not included in the variable

Tags: javascript, var

I am trying to put a condition to check if the `text` variable starts with `https://` or not. If not, I want to add `https://` to the start of `text`.

```
 document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    var text = "https://" + document.getElementById("input").value;
    document.getElementById("iframe").src = text;
    document.getElementById("iframe").height = "100%";
    document.getElementById("iframe").width = "100%";
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = '';
}
```

});

Comment: You can use startsWith("https")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply check if the input `startsWith` what you're looking for..

```
let input = document.getElementById("input").value;
let text = input.startsWith("https://") ? input : "https://" + input;
```

As noted in the comments, the conditional ternary operator has been used here, you can find out more about it here: [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: thanks so much for the help

Answer (score 1):

One approach is:

```
// here we cache the value of the <input> element:
let value = document.getElementById("input").value,
    // we define the protocol we're looking for:
    protocol = 'https://',
    // we then assign the text, using a template-literal string,
    // first we use a conditional operator:
    // which returns a Boolean (true/false), if the
    // String we test starts with the supplied String
    // ('protocol'); if it does we return an empty string
    // and if not we return the protocol variable; and then
    // that's concatenated with the existing 'value'
    // variable:
    text = `${value.startsWith(protocol) ? '' : protocol}${value}`;
```

References:

- [Conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
- [`String.prototype.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith).
- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use includes function to check if the string contains another string.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    let text = document.getElementById("input").value;
    let src = text.includes("https://") ? text : "https://"+text;
    document.getElementById("iframe").src = src;
    document.getElementById("iframe").height = "100%";
    document.getElementById("iframe").width = "100%";
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = '';
  }
});
```

Comment: [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) will return true if the string appears anywhere within the string to which it's chained. It's unusual to see a protocol-like string anywhere but the beginning, but there are occasions in which some services do feature URLs as part of their query parameters.